# character to numeric in data step SAS

Tags: sas, proc, proc-sql

I want to convert some variable into char with defined length and some to numeric with some length in data step. 
How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

for character its working fine.

```
   Data Clean_data
format
country $30.
Region $30.
Days_on_site (Numeric value)
AOD          (Numeric value)

set raw_data;
run;
```

Comment: Show what code you have tried and any log messages you are seeing.  Do you know what a 'numeric with some length' means to a SAS programmer ? Is it different than a numeric format of some width ?

Comment: Why are you using a FORMAT statement? Format's are just instructions for how to display the values.  You can define how a variable is stored by using a LENGTH or ATTRIB statement.

Answer (score 0):

All SAS numeric values in a running DATA step are 8-byte IEEE floating-point. See [Numerical Accuracy in SAS Software](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)  The number of bytes used to store a numeric variable in a data set can be specified to be anywhere from 3 (or 2) to 8 depending on operating system and hardware.  Round off can occur moving a value from a data set into a data step when length is < 8.

SAS Numeric variables can also have an associated format that is used when the value has to be rendered (or presented) for output, generally for human readability.  Output can be most anything, Excel, PDF, RTF, ViewTable viewer, grid viewer in Enterprise Guide, grid viewer in SAS Studio, etc.  This concept *may* align with your question of *"convert some variable into char"*.

There are [many numeric formats](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=n0p2fmevfgj470n17h4k9f27qjag.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en). Based on your variable name `Days_on_site` I would presume you want to format a numeric variable that contains only integer values.  A numeric value can be formatted to show as the nearest integer using

```
format Days_on_site 4.;
```

If the actual value is > 9999 the format will show the value as **** when viewed.

One of the commonly used numeric formats is [***w*.*d***](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=n1n7bmvs1brl23n1dj9cbzau39df.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

From the documentation:

> **w** specifies the width of the output field
>   **d** specifies the number of digits to the right of the
>   decimal point in the numeric value. This argument is optional.